# Render HTML in question summaries?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, markdown

If a question contains a `<s>` tag in the first sentence, this is shown as plain text in the summary in the question list which is confusing.

[Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/syntax-highlighting-and-non-ascii-characters)

As the strikeout is typically used to show where an error was corrected, either the strikeout should be rendered in the summary or the struck text should be hidden.

Comment: It affects sub ans sup too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571140/ways-to-create-a-huge-inverted-index 106 items didn't sound like too big an index

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry, HTML is not rendered in the summary; Markdown is shown as ASCII there too.

Comment: So how about cutting out any text within <s>..</s> in the summary?  That would not require any extra markup.